# Imprimir PDF rellenado con .text

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, formularios, print

Estoy creando un creador de oferta donde existe un formulario estándar y solo sustituye datos de precios y clientes. Por lo que mi intención es imprimir ese formulario relleno con las variables captadas en los Textbox.text

Si alguien me pudiera explicar o dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo lo agredeceria.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para generar el PDF puedes utilizar un NuGet llamado iTextSharp, aqui un ejemplo de su uso:

```
var myDocument = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(ruta, FileMode.Create));
myDocument.Open();
myDocument.Add(new Paragraph("My first PDF"));
myDocument.Close();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a probarlo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo,

Crear una clase que se llame Datos y en la public class Datos vas agregar unas variables de esta forma

```
 public string Orden {get; set;}
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
```

Estas variables recibirán los parámetros

en tu formulario principal donde tendras los txtbox le mandaras el contenido a las variables de Datos de la siguiente manera

```
ReportV c = new ReportV();

                Datos dat = new Datos();

                dat.Orden = (string)this.txtbox1.Value;
                dat.Descripcion = (string)this.txtbox2.Value;

                c.Datos.Add(dat);
            }

            c.Show();
```

Al final es agregar en el report viewer unas celdas y agregar la variable de los datos y ya lo puedes generar y exportar a PDF, EXCEl y demás.

espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a probarlo